# .NET 6 web API receive wrong query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, query-string

I am calling a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) method to my server with a query parameter `courseTierSlug=advanced`, and it receives "avanced" though (missing the letter **d**).
Then I try the word "adtanced" (change the **v** to **t**), and my server get the parameter correctly.
This is such a weird bug that cost me a lot of time researching. I don't know if any configuration in my .NET 6 web API server is missing.

Here are the images for your reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this happen with every word containing "dv"?

Comment: Just curious, did you try to change parameter name in postman from ```CourseTierSlug``` to ```courseTierSlug```?

Comment: I did change the parameter name as you suggested but nothing is different, I have found that the letter right before the first letter 'v' in my string is gonna disappear when it's passed to the server

Comment: What is the context? E.g, what web server (incl. version)? What operating system, incl. edition and version, for the web server? Running where (locally, hosting, cloud, etc.)? What client computer (incl. hardware and operating system (incl. edition and version))? What kind of network connection between the client and the server? Can the problem be isolated to any of these - server, client, network, and to a particular version of those? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77301081/edit), not here -

Comment: cont' - in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***  *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: So what does the task code look like? It's marked out, but the problem is in that task. Whatever it is doing (calling a database I assume?). The data is probably bad in the database or in the data service layer.

Answer (score -2):

It's certainly frustrating when you come across unexpected behavior in your API. The issue you're describing might be related to URL encoding and decoding.

In your case, the query parameter "courseTierSlug=advanced" is interpreted as "avanced" (missing the letter 'd'), but "adtanced" (changing 'v' to 't') is correctly processed.

This discrepancy could be caused by how URL parameters are being encoded or decoded on the client or server side. Make sure that your client is correctly encoding the parameter value before sending it to the server, and your server is properly decoding the query parameters.

On the server side, you might want to check how you're parsing and accessing query parameters. Ensure that there are no unexpected transformations happening at this stage.

Additionally, consider inspecting any middleware or custom logic that might be affecting the query parameter values as they traverse your API pipeline.

If the issue persists, you could share more details about your API configuration, code snippets, or any custom middleware you're using. This would help the community provide more targeted assistance to identify the root cause and find a solution.

Remember, debugging these issues can be a process of elimination, so patience and methodical investigation are key. Don't hesitate to ask for specific help with code or configuration if you need further assistance. Good luck with resolving this unusual bug!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a moment to read [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).  We do hope you'll become a valuable member of the community by posting *your own* quality questions and answers in the future.  Thanks!